# post processing edge

Tags: rendering

new to blender,checking edge in post processing shows up characters wireframe while rendering,like the toon effect,but not the wireframe,what am I supposed to do(blender 2.76),normal render(without edge works fine)

Answer (score 1):

Turn down the Threshold. Edge looks for edges based on z-depth. Threshold changes the limit for this. If threshold is high, or your model is low poly, it will get too many edges.